# Why Jade complains an interpolation variable is undefined?

Tags: pug

When I compile the below code snippt, Jade complains that user_name and user_level are undefined:

```
div.outer
     div.info
         div.user_name  #{user_name}
         div.user_level span.level "LV."+#{user_level}
```

Why?

Comment: Can you also show code where you're defining these variables?  Perhaps you didn't pass these variables when rendering the template?

Comment: @Denis Malinovsky, even I  pass these varaibles, it still complains this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im passing the next vars: `{"user_name": "Bob","user_level": "admin" }` no errors here

these:

```
div.outer
    div.info
        div.user_name  #{user_name}
        div.user_level span.level "LV."+#{user_level}
```

compiles into these:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="user_name"> Bob</div>
        <div class="user_level">span.level "LV."+admin</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

then here is the problem tho: `<div class="user_level">span.level "LV."+admin</div>`

my test runs well when:

```
div.outer
     div.info
         div.user_name  #{user_name}
         div.user_level
             span.level LV.#{user_level}  <----Here you want the dot?
```

compiles into:

```
<div class="outer">
    <div class="info">
        <div class="user_name">Bob</div>
        <div class="user_level"><span class="level">LV.admin</span></div>  <---Looks better.
    </div>
</div>
```

hope it helps

**Part 2**: `for & each` example.

Passing `{"books": ["A", "B", "C"]}`

```
select
  each book, i in books
    option(value=i) Book #{book}
```

Compiles into:

```
<select>
  <option value="0">Book A</option>
  <option value="1">Book B</option>
  <option value="2">Book C</option>
</select>
```

and

```
ul
  for book in books
    li= book
  else
    li sorry, no books!
```

compiles into:

```
<ul>
  <li>A</li>
  <li>B</li>
  <li>C</li>
</ul>
```

case we pass :`{"books": []}`

compiles into:

```
<ul>
    <li>sorry, no books!</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: yeah, I want the dot, the last output is what I want. thanks!

Comment: btw, how could I use interpolation in interation?  For exameple :       `each e in  #{array}` . For the array I want it to be an interpolation, but it couldn't compile. It complains that '#' is Unexpected token ILLEGAL